# Cassandra Start up

Tags: cassandra, startup

I am new to the Cassandra database. I have downloaded Cassandra and set the JAVA_HOME. When I try to run, the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind.
```

Can anyone assist me with this issue?

Comment: try `netstat -tlnp` beforehand to see whether port 7199 is already in use

Comment: I found this line, what to do next.
tcp  0   0   0.0.0.0:7199     0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN      8427/java

Answer (score 15):

For those who are facing the same problem using Ubuntu OS a solution can be to kill CassandraDaemon :

```
pkill -f CassandraDaemon
```

When you launch for the first time the command "cassandra -f" background daemon is running so Ctrl^C doesn't stop the process.

Comment: Thanks @Day, saved my day :P

Comment: I am facing the same issue. how to kill on mac os Mojave - 10.14.4?

Comment: Try something like: pid=$(ps ax | grep CassandraDaemon | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }') && kill -9 $pid

Answer (score 4):

You could check if cassandra is running by checking the port

```
lsof -i :9160
```

if you got a result back that means it is running

If you want to kill it , do `kill -9 "then the pid you got from the last step"`

if you want to see the ongoing log run

```
cassandra -f when you start cassandra
```

Answer (score 3):

Port 7199 is the default Cassandra's JMX port( used for monitoring).
In case you are trying to run multiple instances on one physical machine, modify `$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra-env.sh` configuration file and set different port, for example 7299

```
JMX_PORT="7299"
```

Answer (score 2):

I appears that Cassandra is already running in the background.  Try connecting using `cassandra-cli`.

Comment: I already tried that. After starting the server, I open one more terminal to interact with the thrift using this command: cassandra -cli. and I got the error which I mention above.

Answer (score 2):

1. `ps -ax | grep cassandra`, take note of the process id
2. `kill <pid>`
3. `sudo ./cassandra`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

I am writing the same but for windows developer command prompt :
Let say its showing issue with 9042 port

**netstat -ano | findstr : 9042**

List all the process using port 9042

**taskkill /PID 237979 /F**

here 237979 is the processid which is using port 9042

Answer (score 0):

Download the TCPView from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437

> Open the TCPView application and sort the output by Port
>
> Click on the record which points to Port - 7199
>
> Right click and "End Process"
>
> Now, run the Cassandra.bat and it should work.